# How do I know which way to cast an object in Swift?

Tags: swift

How do I know when I am supposed to use "x as y" instead of "y(x)" when casting objects?

Comment: That's a good question! Bothered me for awhile too, but eventually I got the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Use x as y to down cast or up cast (e.g. cast from base class to  a subclass, or from subclass *toward* base class, respectively)

Use (y)(x) to cast to another type entirely (from float to double or something like that)

y(x) is calling a constructor, not casting.

Comment: Could you explain the difference to me?

Comment: I think OP is likely asking about things like `Int(someDouble)` in his example of `y(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

casting in swift is done with as and as?

x as y or x as? y

doing y(x) is not casting you are creating a new variable of type y

Comment: It's all good.  Ya win some and ya lose some.  In the long run our efforts pay off. Cheers.